# Asking to do a POST with RestKit using CoreData Tutorial/Example

Tags: ios, post, core-data, restkit

I want to do a POST of an CoreData entity called 'Contacts' but in the JSON file who I will send I need to include others params like the 'UserId' of the user who has this contacts. 
I think that RestKit with CoreData only sends the full entity of 'Contacts' without any other params.
Anyone knows how to do it?.
Thanks

Comment: Are the other parame is a related object, or a container?

Comment: String. Like this:
 "{
      "userid": "687041328",  <-----
      "devices": {
          "os": "Android",
          "date_at": 1446653838,
          "latitude": 2.1,
          "longitude": 2.2
      }
}

Comment: Well, you'll need to unpack it from a string to something else at least.